# How to insert value in the table having it primary key in symfony

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I want to insert a value having already defined id in the table which have auto increment column id(PK) in doctrine symfony.

Comment: Hi, please read this before posting a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Your question is not complaint with StackOverflow standards as it lacks of details and is too much abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : generally you should not update the id of an existing row in the dataBase.

But However.. Assuming that your entity look like has fields : `ID` and `nameValue` :

```
$car = $carsRepository->find(10); // select a car which the id is 10
$car->setId(1025); // note that : by default your entity DOES NOT have a built method setID() so you have to write it.
$car->setNameValue("Opel");
$manager->flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ID generator temporarily to store given primary ids like:

```php
use App\Entity\YourEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AssignedGenerator;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

$entity = new YourEntity();
$entity->setId(101);
$entity->setSomething('foo');

$entityManager->persist($entity);

// change the ID generator temporarily before flushing
$metadata = $entityManager->getClassMetaData(YourEntity::class);
$metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
$metadata->setIdGenerator(new AssignedGenerator());

$entityManager->flush();
```